# How to remove some packages which contain a certain keyword?

Tags: apt, aptitude, pipe

For example, when I want to remove Xfce, I did this:

```
 aptitude search xfce | grep ^i

id  gtk2-engines-xfce               - GTK+-2.0 theme engine for Xfce            
id  libxfce4ui-common               - common files for libxfce4ui               
id  libxfce4util-common             - common files for libxfce4util
```

I want to get the second column and pass them to `aptitude remove`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get` supports regular expressions. Just include a `.`, `*` or `?` in the package name to make it an expression:

```
apt-get remove 'xfce.'
```

From [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get):

```
If no package matches the given expression and the expression
contains one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX
regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the
database. Any matches are then installed (or removed). Note that
matching is done by substring so 'lo.*' matches 'how-lo' and
'lowest'. If this is undesired, anchor the regular expression with
a '^' or '$' character, or create a more specific regular
expression.
```

Comment: Thank you. This works when the string is at the begining. I have to run `apt-get remove '.xfce'` again to clean all of them up. Does aptitude support regular expressions?

Comment: @Nick Tried `.*xfce.*`? With `aptitude` the syntax is different, try `aptitude remove '~xfce'`.

Comment: I've removed all the xfce packages. I think .*xfce.* would work. Thank you. The aptitude syntax is weird. I'll search for its documentation to learn the usage. By the way, which do you prefer, apt-get or aptitude?

Comment: @Nick Since `aptitude` is not installed by default, `apt-get` (or `apt`, now). But there are some things for which `aptitude` is the right tool.